# Парсинг выдает ошибку "Метод ** в типе ** неприменим для аргументов"

Tags: парсер

Совсем недавно начал изучать Android и парсинг, поэтому прошу Вас помочь мне:
Имеется код, но он выдает ошибку

*"Метод add(HashMap) в типе ArrayList> неприменим для аргументов 
 (HashMap)"*

в строке:

```
                        hashmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();  
                    hashmap.put("title",title);
                    hashmap.put("description",description);
                    hashmap.put("imageURL",imageURL);
                    myList.add(hashmap);
```

А именно на myList.add(hashmap);

Как я понял, идет какое то не соответствие типов ключа:значение. Возможно ошибаюсь.
Объясните пожалуйста, как нужно правильно написать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте либо

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> myList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
```

либо

```
hashmap.put(...,title.toString());
```

Вы пытаетесь положить в лист хеша строки от строки хеш объектов от строки.

Comment: благодарствую! :)

Comment: @BTCY В этом форуме благодарность принято выражать поднятием репутации (нажать на символ поднятого вверх большого пальца с левой стороны от ответа)

Comment: Я первым делом так и сделал, но мне сказали что чтобы поставить палец вверх нужна репутация как минимум 15, а у меня 11 :( поэтому только на словах

Comment: @BTCY Поднимай, теперь можешь...

Comment: @BTCY Я же здесь http://hashcode.ru/questions/255455#255494 дал Вам ответ на Ваш вопрос. Зачем вы изменили Object на String?

Comment: @vanyamelikov я не углядел этот момент, не знаю почему. Копировал и разбирался с Вашего примера. Как то так получилось со String-ом. Умышленно я не менял там Object на String, поскольку разобрался что к чему:) Ну благо, сейчас все работает :). Еще раз спасибо за подробнейшее разъяснение :) 
А по поводу вывода картинки Вы можете подсказать? Как вывести картинку по URL

Comment: @BTCY по URL? С кешированием или без?

Comment: @vanyamelikov Ну смысли, отображение картинок. Там-веть ссылки в JSON списке, что бы картинки из ссылок отобразились

Comment: @BTCY задай отдельный вопрос, постараюсь поподробнее написать! Здесь как бы не совсем корректно!